# Displaying a dictionary in IPython recalculates the hashes

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, ipython

Strangly, if I display a dictionary in `IPython` it seems to recalculate the hashes of the keys. This behaviour doesn't happen in normal python interpreters and I would like to know what the reason for this could be.

An example:

```
class Fun(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        print('hashing')
        return hash(self._value)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Fun):
            return self._value == other._value
        else:
            return self._value == other

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self._value)
```

when creating the dictionary the `hash` are obviously needed:

```
In [2]: dict1 = {Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}
hashing
hashing
```

But it surprised me when I displayed the dictionary later:

```
In [3]: dict1
Out[3]: hashing
hashing
{Fun(11): 5, Fun(10): 5}
```

This doesn't happen if I use the `repr` or `items`:

```
In [4]: dict1.items()
Out[4]: [(Fun(10), 5), (Fun(11), 5)]

In [5]: repr(dict1)
Out[5]: '{Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}'
```

Normally I wouldn't care but I'm looking into some performance issues with a class that has a very expensive `hash` method and it seems unreasonably to me why displaying `dict1` (especially opposed to `repr(dict1)`) should recalculate the `hash` of the keys.

But the question isn't just about the why (even that's what is really interesting me), I would also be very interested in how to **disable** that. I'm using IPython 5.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting.  I added a pdb.set_trace() into the hashing function, and tried printing dict1. Once in pdb, I used the "where" command to see the stack:

```
In [16]: dict1
Out[16]: > <ipython-input-14-01f77f64262f>(6)__hash__()
-> print('hashing')
(Pdb) where
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/bin/ipython(11)<module>()
-> sys.exit(start_ipython())
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py(119)start_ipython()
-> return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py(596)launch_instance()
-> app.start()
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py(344)start()
-> self.shell.mainloop()
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py(550)mainloop()
-> self.interact(display_banner=display_banner)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py(674)interact()
-> self.run_cell(source_raw, store_history=True)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(2723)run_cell()
-> interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(2831)run_ast_nodes()
-> if self.run_code(code, result):
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(2885)run_code()
-> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  <ipython-input-16-8239e7494a4a>(1)<module>()
-> dict1
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py(246)__call__()
-> format_dict, md_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py(152)compute_format_data()
-> return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py(177)format()
-> data = formatter(obj)
  <decorator-gen-10>(2)__call__()
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py(222)catch_format_error()
-> r = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py(699)__call__()
-> printer.pretty(obj)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py(368)pretty()
-> return self.type_pprinters[cls](obj, self, cycle)
  /usr/local/virtualenvs/lab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py(623)inner()
-> p.pretty(obj[key])
> <ipython-input-14-01f77f64262f>(6)__hash__()
-> print('hashing')
```

Looks like the ipython shell is trying hard to pretty-print the result.  The pretty.py code is:

```
for idx, key in p._enumerate(keys):
    if idx:
        p.text(',')
        p.breakable()
    p.pretty(key)
    p.text(': ')
    p.pretty(obj[key])
```

Looking up `obj[key]` involves hashing the key again.

Can this be avoided? Not sure! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with putting the dictionary, or a copy, in the `Out` dictionary.  Other methods of displaying or referencing the dictionary don't do this

```
In [7]: d
Out[7]: hashing
hashing
{Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}
In [8]: d;
In [9]: d
Out[9]: hashing
hashing
{Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}
In [10]: d;
In [11]: print(d)
{Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}
In [12]: str(d)
Out[12]: '{Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}'
In [13]: repr(d)
Out[13]: '{Fun(10): 5, Fun(11): 5}'

In [21]: id(d)
Out[21]: 2977840716
In [22]: id(Out[7])
Out[22]: 2977840716
```

This may just a another way of looking the pretty print issue.

Deep copy does the rehashing, shallow does not:

```
In [28]: {k:v for k,v in d.items()};
hashing
hashing
In [29]: d1 = {}
In [30]: d1.update(d)
In [32]: import copy
In [33]: copy.copy(d);
In [34]: copy.deepcopy(d);
hashing
hashing
```

With a larger dictionary, e.g. `db={Fun(i):i for i in range(15)}`, the Ipython display is multiline.  Interesting though, `pprint.pprint(db)` prints multiline without rehashing (but with a different key order).